# Declaring variable in static text display document name on page

Tags: kentico

I have problem with declaration of variable in static text web part text field. When I use code like this:

```
{% doc = Documents.WithAllData[CurrentDocument.Children["Hero"].Children[0].GetValue("NodeAliasPath")]; #%}

<p>
  {% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.HeroButtonLabel)) { %}
  <a class="btn btn-secondary arrow" href="{% doc.HeroUrl #%}">
    {% doc.HeroButtonLabel #%}
  </a>
  {% } #%}
  {% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc.HeroUrl2Label)) { %}
  <a class="btn btn-secondary arrow" href="{% doc.HeroUrl2 #%}">
    {% doc.HeroUrl2Label #%}
  </a>
  {% } #%}
</p>
```

first line displays document name on rendered page (the rest of code works fine). I use Kentico 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a return statement, so that your line reads as follows:

```
{% 
  doc = Documents.WithAllData[CurrentDocument.Children["Hero"].Children[0].GetValue("NodeAliasPath")];
  return;
#%}
```